# More than one __attribute__ in C with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

Can you add more than one attribute to an identifier in C with gcc?
Here is what I have now.  I left out the include statements because they get scramble in the post.
If there is a way to add two, what is the general syntax, and how can I do it both with the defintion, and with a prototype? Thank you. :-)

```
main() {  
    printf("In Main\n");  
}  
__attribute__ ((constructor)) void beforeMain(void)  
{  
    printf("Before Main\n");  
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are two different ways of specifying multiple attributes in C with GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Attributes in prototypes:
__attribute__((constructor, weak)) void beforeMain(void);
__attribute__((constructor)) __attribute__((weak)) void beforeMain2(void);

int main(){
    printf("In Main\n");
    return 0;
}

// Attributes in definitions:
__attribute__((constructor, weak)) void beforeMain(void){
    printf("Before Main 1\n");
}

__attribute__((constructor)) __attribute__((weak)) void beforeMain2(void){
    printf("Before Main 2\n");
}
```

The code above compiles and runs correctly for me under GCC versions 4.4.3 and 12.3.0.

Comment: lol, pmg.  Most of the time I work with tiny microcontrollers, where the return value of main() is pointless.  Somehow the "void main" code compiled without a warning in GCC.  But I changed it to return an int to make you happy :)

Comment: +1 -- I'm happy now, thank you @David. If you compile with `-Wall` (or only just `-Wmain`), gcc will complain about `void main` :)

Comment: Thank you :-), that definitely answers my question.

Comment: can we add attribute in a separate file? for example in file a.h define an array with an attribute and in another file b.h, add another attribute for the same array. if it's possible, it would be convenient. (changing the variable attribute according to compile macro)

Comment: @ChanKim Not possible, it seems. The compiler need to know the attributes at the point of compilation. This said, you can probably define a macro that contains the necessary attributes (according to other conditions, including values of other macros), and use the macro in the source code.

Answer (score 10):

You can use multiple __attribute__ specifiers separated by spaces.

```
char s[3] __attribute__((aligned(32))) __attribute__((weak));
```

Comment: This answers my question as well, but can't accept two answers :-(

Comment: np.  Grayson has the throrougher answer here.